# $A$, $B$ have all $\lambda \geq 0$, null($A$) $=$ null($A^2$), null($B$) $=$ null($B^2$). Prove that if $A^2 = B^2$, then $A=B$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**Problem**

Let $A$, $B \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$. Suppose the eigenvalues of $A$, $B$ are all non-negative real numbers, and that null($A$) $=$ null($A^2$) and null($B$) $=$ null($B^2$). If $A^2 = B^2$, prove that $A=B$.

Comment: Is $\operatorname{null}$ the nullity (a number) or the kernel (a subspace)?

Comment: @KennyLau in this case the number is sufficient, so I suspect that is what they mean.

Comment: The nullity condition simply means that $A$ and $B$ have not any nontrivial nilpotent Jordan block in their Jordan forms (i.e. if zero is an eigenvalue, it is semisimple). It is here to ensure that, subject to this condition, the square root of a zero matrix is unique. The rest are pretty standard: just find a square root $X$ of $A^2$ that has a nonnegative spectrum, satisfies the nullity condition, and is a polynomial in $A^2$; then show that both $A,B$ are equal to $X$.

Comment: construct $S \in GL_n(\mathbb C)$ having its first vectors as a basis for $\ker A^2$ and the rest as a basis for $\text{im } A^2$, then $S^{-1}AS =\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf 0 & \mathbf 0 \\ 
\mathbf 0  & A'
\end{bmatrix}$ and $S^{-1}BS =\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf 0 & \mathbf 0 \\ 
\mathbf 0  & B'
\end{bmatrix}$ where $A' = B'$ follows from the duplicate link