# $A$, $B$ have all $\lambda\geq 0$, null($A$)=null($A^2$), null($B$)=null($B^2$), $A^4=B^4$, then $A=B$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**Problem**

Let $A,B\in M_n(\mathbb C)$. Suppose $\text{null}A=\text{null}A^2,\text{null}B=\text{null}B^2$ and the spectrums of $A$ and $B$ are nonnegative. If $A^4=B^4$, then $A=B$.

**Similar Question**

[$A$, $B$ have all $\lambda \geq 0$, null($A$) $=$ null($A^2$), null($B$) $=$ null($B^2$). Prove that if $A^2 = B^2$, then $A=B$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2586670/a-b-have-all-lambda-geq-0-nulla-nulla2-nullb-nul)

I know that if I can solve the similar question above, then this problem is just a straightforward corollary. However, the answer in the link, as far as I'm concerned, is quite vague; so I am here craving for an extra explanation.

Comment: You should edit your post to specify what $\lambda$ is.

Comment: I've marked that as a duplicate of a question asked last month.  You should know that original posters are expected to show some effort.